# Система строительства в Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, 2d

Возникла проблема с системой строительства в Unity2D, скрины с объектов инспектора:

[image: Скрины с инспектора]

Код скрипта тайлмапа:

```
public class BuildingsGrid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2Int GridSize = new Vector2Int(10, 10);

private Building[,] grid;
private Building FlyingBuilding;
[SerializeField] private Camera mainCamera;

private void Awake()
{
    grid = new Building[GridSize.x, GridSize.y];
    
    mainCamera = Camera.main;
}

public void StartPlacingBuilding(Building buildingPrefab)
{
    if (FlyingBuilding != null)
    {
        Destroy(FlyingBuilding.gameObject);
    }
    FlyingBuilding = Instantiate(buildingPrefab);
}

private void Update()
{
    Debug.Log(mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
    Vector2 mouseWorldPosition = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    

    if (FlyingBuilding != null)
    {
        int x = Mathf.RoundToInt(mouseWorldPosition.x);
        int y = Mathf.RoundToInt(mouseWorldPosition.y);
        
        FlyingBuilding.transform.position = new Vector2(x, y);
        
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            FlyingBuilding = null;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
            Destroy(FlyingBuilding.gameObject);
    }

    }
}
```

Код скрипта строения:

```
public class Building : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2Int Size = Vector2Int.one;

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < Size.x; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Size.y; y++)
            {
                Gizmos.color = new Color(0.88f, 0f, 1f, 0.3f);

                Gizmos.DrawCube(transform.position + new Vector3(x, y, 0), new Vector3(1, 1, 0));

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Здание выбирается по кнопке, летает за курсором, но возникла проблема с его постановкой.

При нажатии на кнопку здание ставится (сразу под кнопкой) и тут же создаётся новое вместо того, чтобы старое просто уничтожалось. Как понял, здесь нужно использовать  Ray2D или RaycastHit2D, но мне не хватает навыков (в гугле не забанили, но не нашёл решения).

Пытался адаптировать код с гайда где был показан пример для 3D.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Можете добавить скрипт с  Building? А то я не могу нормально воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: Точно. Совсем из головы вылетело... Обновил вопрос, добавил.

Comment: Не совсем понятно что такое "grid" и зачем он нужен. Откуда берется GridSize.x, GridSize.y, что у Вас в инспекторе?

Comment: Обновил, как оказалось, забыл вчера ещё кусок кода, простите... Опять же, писалось всё по гайду на 3D, там (на сколько я понял) человече добавлял Buildings Grid для создания сетки строительства на плоскости, в моём случае это наверное лишнее. Параметр Size у скрипта Building - для отрисовки квадрата под зданием во время строительства.

Comment: Да, обновили, и убрали код для Building

Comment: Первый пост комом... Я сейчас со стыда сгорю. Исправил. Проверил. Теперь всё должно быть нормально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На деле всё оказалось очень просто. Первая проблема с постановкой здания вместо уничтожения решилась правкой кода, а именно -

Вместо:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        Destroy(FlyingBuilding);
```

Прописал это:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        Destroy(FlyingBuilding.gameObject);
```

Вторая проблема (с постановкой здания сразу под кнопкой при её повторном нажатии) решилась так:

```
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() == false)
            FlyingBuilding = null;
```